# Segregate class names using regular expresions

Tags: java, regex

I have input like this and I need out put map like below. How can I do it.

**Input**

```
AccountDTO
UserDAO
TransferDTO
DepositDAO
```

**Output**

```
DAO
   UserDAO
   DepositDAO
DTO
   AccountDTO
   TransferDTO
```

DTO

Comment: Why is `DAO` the magic word? Is it "Any class that ends in the letters DAO or DTO need to become part of a list associated with the word 'DTO' / 'DAO' - the output _always_ is a map with 2 keys (DTO and DAO)". Is it: "Any sequence of capitals at the end becomes a key". Or is it something else? Why is DAO 'first'? Does order not matter, or is it alphabetical, or something else? I don't think this question can be answered well without further detail.

Comment: based on provided information, assuming the names should be grouped by the last 3 characters and that the input is a String, you can use  `input.lines().collect(groupingBy(s -> s.substring(s.length()-3
)))` to create a `Map` with the grouped data, which can then be output as needed -- not clear what is the role of the regular expression (from the title)

Comment: "*[Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)*"